# Rails find by attribute in association array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have two model A and B. A has_many B's. B has an attribute :number

What is the rails way (I could do some coding with each, but that's not the point) to find if an A has a B object with a given number ?

I've tried find but since it's an association, it gives me this error:

```
>> bs.find{|f| f.number == 8}
>> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find A without an ID
```

**EDIT**

To make more clear.

If I had to code this would be something like:

```
def is_number_in_use(number)?
    self.bs.each do |b| #Consider bs as the has_many association between A and B
        return true if b.numero == number
    end
    return false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that better?

```
a.bs.select{ |b| b.number == 8 }.any? #=> return true if a has one b o more with number == 8
```

Comment: But shouldn't this generate an SQL query ? I want to avoid that. And I wouldn't have the b_id, I want to search for the number in all B's related to A.

Comment: I updated my answer. What kind of method do you want? Returning true of false ? Or returning the A object which has at least one B object with number == 8 ?

Comment: true or false. And to not generate a new SQL Query, there's no need for that.

Comment: the `any?` will test if the Array is empty, or not and return `true|false`

Comment: Just to complement. I used the any? directly:

`a.bs.any?{ |b| b.number == 9}`

Answer (score 1):

`find` on your association is being over-ridden by ActiveRecord. I think what you want is `Enumerable#select`:

```
bs = B.all
bs_with_number_eq_8 = bs.select {|f| f.number == 8}
```

That won't generate a SQL query but will just iterate over the collection `bs` and filter them on `number == 8`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want.
Can you put much code and I can have more information.

Also you can try this:

> bs.find{|f| f.try(:number) == 8}

Comment: as @Cody said the find method is overriden by the ActiveRecord find method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
def is_number_in_use(number)?
  self.bs.collect(&:number).include?(number)
end
```

**Update**

```
self.bs.where(:number => some_number).present? #this will return true or false
```

and this will call only one sql query.

Comment: Ok. This shoud work. But the whole point of my question is to avoid a method, is to use rails defaults. (like select, ou any?). 

As I said in the question, I could have done with a method, but I wanted to figure out a ruby/rails way of doing it.

Comment: Ok. Call only one sql query. But I will use this code inside a loop. I have to check if the number is being used before update the record, and I receive a list of records, so in the end, this will generates list.size queries.